# c# compare two strings for a matching word (case insensitive)

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have a keyword `Person`. I have a list that has elements inside such as `Person A`,`Apple`, `Person B`,`Pear` , `Person C` ,`Banana`

I am trying to get the elements in the list that contains the keyword .

```
for(int i =0; i < list.items.count; i++){
   if (keyword == list[i])
      Console.WriteLine("Person")
}
```

Im trying the code above and it does not seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Change `if (keyword == list[i])` to `if (list[i].Contains(keyword))`

Comment: I understand that `Person A` is considered as `Person`. What about `Personal`? I'm guessing that should not be considered as `Person`. The easy way to do a comparison like that is with regular expressions.

Comment: @praty that would also pass things like `Personal`. I'm guessing that should not pass.

Comment: I don't 100% agree with the duplicate, but it should be enough to answer the question (therefore no reopen vote from me). The title contradicts the actual question *"I am trying to get the elements in the list that contains the keyword ."* a bit.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, since the other question is looking for a simple contains, while this one is looking for containing a **word**.However, the accepted answer to that question does raise an important detail about case insensitivity I'm not sure a lot of people are even aware of.